# Error message: Value of the StartSearchLocation '' is not a valid GUID. '{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}' will be used instead

Tags: content-search

I'm seeing this error repeatedly in the logs in our CM instance of Sitecore 8.1 update-3. Where does it come from?

> ERROR Value of the StartSearchLocation '' is not a valid GUID. '{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}' will be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found that this is coming from the `Buckets/Services/Search.aspx` handler (`ItemBuckets.Services.Search.ProcessRequestAsync()` in the `Sitecore.Buckets.Client` dll). It happens when you use the Search for Content tab of the Select the Associated Content dialog that appears when it's time to select the datasource for a rendering:

[image: select the associated content dialog]

Behind the scenes, what's happening is it's executing a query to the search service, but in the search service it looks at the referrer for the selected item to use as the `StartSearchLocation`:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
Uri urlReferrer = request.UrlReferrer;
if (urlReferrer != null)
{
    item = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlReferrer.Query)["id"];
}
item = item ?? (request.Form["StartSearchLocation"] ?? request.QueryString["StartSearchLocation"]);
```

Unfortunately, the previous request was to `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/DataSourceResult.aspx` with no query string and the search is executed without a `StartSearchLocation` parameter in the form or the query string, so there is no value to pull for a `StartSearchLocation` and it falls back to the default root item.

## A "fix"

According to Sitecore Support, this has been fixed in Sitecore 8.2 update-1. They also confirmed that it does not affect functionality (other than the performance of throwing and catching the exception). In the meantime, they suggest simply suppressing these messages from the logs by adding a filter to the default `LogFileAppender`:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <log4net>
            <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SitecoreLogFileAppender, Sitecore.Logging">
                <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
                    <stringToMatch value="Value of the StartSearchLocation '' is not a valid GUID"/>
                    <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
                </filter>
            </appender>
        </log4net>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### A (not-so-great) alternative

Alternatively, one could decompile the class, create a custom version that handles the `LocationFilter` more gracefully, and then update the `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Buckets\Services\Search.ashx` file to point to the custom class. I've personally decided not to do that for two reasons:

1. It means customizing something deep in Sitecore that is frequently used
2. This is a relatively minor issue